# Get Value in Array Value in HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap

```
 "results": 
[
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "Data": {
                "id": 23
            }
        }
]
```

I have a json returning like this and I meet it with HashMap, but I can access the Data array. How can I get the id in the data array?

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> personList = getCurrentResponse().jsonPath().getList("results");
   for (HashMap<String, Object> person : personList ) {
      if (person .get("name").equals(name)) {
          int id= (int) (person .get("Data.id"));
          return id;
```

I am getting NullException from the code sample above

Comment: You need to `get` the object keyed by `Data`, and then `get` the object of *that* keyed by `id`.

Comment: Can you help me with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get Data as a HashMap, and then get id from it:

```
HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) person .get("Data");
int id= (int) (data.get("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve only one level at a time, you may call `.get()` twice

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> person : personList ) {
    if (person .get("name").equals(name)) {
        return person.get("Data").get("id");
    }
}
```

Comment: @MehmetSerkanEkinci what do you mean ?